# cookie and bearer authentication with angular MVC web API architecutre

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my current project i have following arcitecture
MVC application wrapping angularJS application (one action is provided to load templates for TemplateUrl in angularjs. Views are .cshtml instead of simple HTML pages which gives me flexibility to use Razor engine and do simple things like checking if users is in role and not render HTML template part.

second project is Web API project. once AngularJS application is loaded, it makes direct calls to API endpoint and uses MVC only for template loading.

MVC+AngularJS is hosted on -> subdomain.mydomain.com
WEB API is hosted on -> subdomain2.mydomain.com

currently app works without any issues, but i need to add authentication so the problem is;

1. how can i implement authentication flow in a way, that, If user is not authenticated it is redirected to the MVC login page,
2. Once it gets authenticated it gets authenticated in Web API as well.
3. If request is made to load template i can access authenticated user
   roles.
4. if API call is made to API WEB API can check for authentication as
   well?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i implement authentication flow in a way, that, If user is not authenticated it is redirected to the MVC login page,

You can do this by enabling Forms Authentication in you application. You can get number of documents online if you google that out.

> Once it gets authenticated it gets authenticated in Web API as well.

WebApis are designed to be stateless. For authenticating there, use token based authentication where once user is authenticated, pass in a token with each webAPI request which can be validated at server before processing the request.

> If request is made to load template i can access authenticated user roles.

Once user is authenticated you can cache user roles associated with the user's session and use that to identify his roles.

> if API call is made to API WEB API can check for authentication as well?

Use Authentication token for this for identifying each request that will be sent from client.

Comment: ok on a high level i understand how all this can be done, but in an underlying implementation can u bring any example of this? i mean if i enable forms authentication on MVC side. when to i authenticate against API to obtain token? what flow type to use?

Comment: This link can help you. One of the case I have seen is where they were using SessionID generated after login as authentication token. that way same infrastructure can be used. But then Session hijack can happen. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: You get the idea, google out yourself. I am not going to write code for you.

Comment: ok thank i did not asked u to write code :) i was asking which flow to use so i think Password will be fine.